# Update problem in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: updates, update-manager

Whenever I am trying to update using  sudo apt-get update I am facing the following errors:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/InRelease  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-1386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/mpv-tests/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-1386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
```

How to fix this error?

Comment: What is the output of:   cat -n /etc/apt/sources.list

Comment: Can you also give the output of:   ls /etc/apt/sources.list | grep mc3man

Answer (score 0):

You can regenerate your `/etc/apt/sources.list` content from [this link](https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/) and then enter:

```
sudo apt-get update
```